# Uknown reason for segmentation fault using sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault

This is the server side code for communication through sockets in C. I am getting a segmentation fault but I can understand why its occurring. Here is the code:

```
int server_sd ; // The socket descriptor

server_sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (server_sd == -1) {
    cout << "Could not create socket";
} else {
    cout << "Socket created" << endl;
}

struct protoent *proto;
proto = getprotobyname("http");

struct sockaddr_in addr;
cout << "sockaddr is created" << endl;

memset((void *)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
cout << "memset is done";

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = proto->p_proto;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; /* any interface */

cout << "Binding server now:" << endl;

if( bind(server_sd,(sockaddr *)&addr , sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
    //print the error message
    perror("bind failed. Error");
} else {
    cout << "bind done" << endl;
}

listen(server_sd, 10); /* make into listener with 10 slots */

cout << "Waiting for incoming connections..." << endl;
```

I am using cout statements to trace where the problem is occuring. Here is the output of the program :

```
Socket created
sockaddr is created

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: A debugger will be able to tell you more specifically where the error occurred. Did you check the return value of `getprotobyname`?

Comment: Check value of `proto` before dereferencing. The `cout << "memset is done";` is probably being buffered leading you to believe it is the `memset()` causing the problem.

Comment: A debugger is definitely what you want!! Having said that, `cout` won't flush until you flush it manually or you do an `endl`. Your "memset is done" doesn't have one.

Comment: run in gdb and look at the stack trace

Comment: Can you use gdb or other debugger to see exactly what values are being passed in to memset? I don't see anything wrong... Try moving the memset to the first possible line does it still crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably crashing here:

```
addr.sin_port = proto->p_proto;
```

`proto` might be NULL.

The reason you don't see `memset is done` printed is because you don't have any `<< endl` there, and `cout` will buffer the data until it sees a newline or it's explicitly flushed.

Comment: Agreed--there is no "http" protocol in /etc/protocols on my system at least.